# Is having an A-B index as well as a B-A index excessive?

Tags: postgresql

Am I right in thinking that having two indexes 'A-B and B-A' is a mistake, because you can always do 'A-B and B' which has no downsides and has less upkeep work?

My logic is if you were wanting to filter by both columns in B-A, you could just use the A-B index.

This seems watertight to me, but I wanted to check whether there are any edge cases or other considerations involved.

Comment: Looks like premature optimization. Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement? And the statement  itself. The DDL for the table and indexes involved would be helpful as well. Al in plain text of course. And run your tests on a large enough database, an almost empty database/table will always result in a sequential scan because that's the best one when there is (almost) no data.

Comment: consider a large dataset with cases like `... where a > 123 and b = 456`

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes JGH has pointed out a counterexample in the comments.

Having `B-A` is superior to `A-B` and `B` if you are doing the following:

```sql
... where a > 123 and b = 456
```

In this case you're not using equality for a, so you need b to be first in the index.

---

Similarly I also thought about using an `order by`:

```sql
... where b = 5 order by a limit 1
```

Here `B-A` is a covering index. This won't work for `A-B` and `B`.

Edit: You don't even need `order by`. You'd have to do `select a` for it to be covering anyway (not `select *`, which would need to fetch other columns from the main table).